# May I Use script that Stored into Include File (such as test.inc) into WebForm.aspx?

Tags: html, asp.net, webforms, include

May I Use script that Stored into Include File (such as test.inc) into WebForm.aspx?
if answer is yes how i do it else propose to me an alternative way my Problem like this :

```
//----- Footer.inc ------
 Copyright <% DateTime.Now.Year %> , My Company Name .
 ---------------  
   // ----- Default.aspx ----
          <td class="ColRightStyle" colspan="2">
               <% Response.WriteFile("Includes/Footer.inc"); %>
          </td>
```

but result in browser is :

Copyright <% DateTime.Now.Year %> , My Company Name .

(Right => Copyright 2014 , My Company Name .)

i take time and search into related question but i did not found an question and answer like this
tnx so mush

Comment: You should probably take a look at [ASP.NET Master Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.ASPX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use This :

```
<td class="ColRightStyle" colspan="2">
                    <% Response.WriteFile("Includes/Footer.inc"); %>

                </td>
```

and in Footer.inc File :

```
<div class="FooterStyle" dir="rtl" >

       Copyright , Notice &nbsp; &copy;
        <br /></div>
        <div class="FooterStyle" dir="ltr"  >
        &copy;&nbsp;Copyright by www.Google.com ; 2004 - <% =DateTime.Now.Year %>


    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why are you doing this, you can read the file content and parse it, but it still won't give you what you seek.
For instance: `<% DateTime.Now.Year %>` should be `<%= DateTime.Now.Year %>` to get the value you want, which doesn't conform to php inc files.

If, however, you want to do this, you can use [Custom Expression Builders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.expressionbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) 
[Here is an article that covers the subject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33056/How-to-use-a-custom-expression-builder-to-provide)

BTW, If you want to read the contents, try this:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Include/Footer.inc"))
```